# Remove specific brackets from string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, substring

I have a list of say:

```
(UH[0], UH[1], UH[2], UH[3].... )
```

I want to use re.sub to remove everything from each element of the list except the number so that it is

```
(0 , 1 , 2 , 3 .....)
```

I tried with:

```
re.sub ('[UH^[]]' ,'', each_element)
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you are only just learning Python, you should probably ignore Python 2 and focus on the currently recommended supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

`re.findall` might be an option too:

```
import re

string = 'UH[0], UH[1], UH[2], UH[3].... '
print(re.findall(r'\d+', string))
```

#### Output

```
['0', '1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace them like

```
In [1]: x = "UH[0], UH[1], UH[2], UH[3]"

In [2]: result = x.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("UH", "")

In [3]: result
Out[3]: '0, 1, 2, 3'
```

Hope it helps.